# Design Pattern for List of Immutable Objects usage

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

Lets say I have an object of type `Foo`, which when initialized, will be `immutable`. Since these objects are immutable, and I want to be able to access any of these `Foo` objects, I initialize and store these objects in a `static class` (`FooHandler`) which contains a `list` of all the `Foo` objects.

Currently however, if a class wants to access this object, I give them the index of where the `Foo` object is located in the list in `FooHandler`, and have a `getter method` to return the object itself when needed. The intent of this is to save on memory by not having two of the same objects in circulation (which I consider a waste).

Is there a better approach in **C#** for referencing these objects (like a pointer or something similar) or a better structure entirely for how to approach this problem, as I feel giving an index to an immutable object is too hackish and error prone?

**Example code:**

```
public class Foo {
    public int A { get; private set; }
    public int B { get; private set; }

    public Foo(int a, int b) {
        A = a;
        B = b;
    }
}

public static class FooHandler {
    private static List<Foo> fooList;

    static FooHandler() {
        fooList = new List<Foo>();

        fooList.Add(new Foo(1, 2));
        fooList.Add(new Foo(3, 4));
    }

    // Assume there is error checking
    public static Foo GetFoo(int index) {
        return fooList[index];
    }
}

public class Bar {
    public int FooID { get; private set; }

    public Bar(int fooID) {
        FooID = fooID;
    }

    public void func() {
        Console.WriteLine(FooHandler.GetFoo(FooID).A);
    }
}
```

**Note:** I know this example could be considered mutable, just wanted to type something up quickly without too much testing.

Comment: Unless you are using `struct`s you would not have two objects, just two variables pointing at the same single object.

Comment: The pattern you are describing is the composite pattern. If you changed FooHandler into something that implements an interface that Foo also implements, you'd have the pattern matched exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# already passes around reference types (denoted by `class`) with a reference (roughly equivalent to a pointer).

You need not do anything special to get this and it happens automatically. There is no waste in just returning the `Foo` directly.

Comment: So if I made a Foo object in Bar equal to one instantiated in FooHandler's list with the GetFoo method to access the element, it isn't a clone, but a reference to that object?

Comment: @Hayden: Correct, if `Bar` has a `Foo` named `V` then `V = FooHandler.GetFoo(fooID);` would mean that `V` holds a reference to the `Foo` (as that is how all reference types work).